# can I extract overlap of polygons within the same layer?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, polygon, intersection, overlapping-features

I am trying to extract the overlap of polygons that are within the same layer in 10. The layer came from a buffered street centerline and I'm trying to extract and delete the intersections from the layer.
I have tried 'intersect' but it's virtually impossible to tell which records are an overlap and which ones are not. We are trying Shape tools but so far the computer gave an 'overflow' error.

Answer (score 6):

I think I would use the [intersect command](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Intersect/00080000000p000000/)
Then use that data to select your overlapping polygons.

Comment: I have tried 'intersect' but the output includes all records, overlap and the non-overlap, because all polygons are in the same layer. It comes up with over 212k records (we started with 13k) because the overlap has multiple records. There doesn't seem to be a good system to separate overlap from non overlap.

I am using ARCGIS 10, desktop. I am trying to identify the overlap of polygons within the same class. I will apply a buffer to the overlap and use that to clip another layer.

In any case, to problem is that the overlapping polygons I'm trying to identify are in the same data layer.

Comment: @Julia, Have you adding the layer into the dialog by itself (just once)?  You don't want to add it twice, otherwise you will end up with duplicate features, like you are describing.

Comment: +1 - Found this question and answer really helpful - so simple, yet brilliant. Also didn't know that Intersect could be used on a single input (my colleagues didn't know either).

Comment: That was so helpful! I also didn't know you could use intersect on a single layer. Thanks.

Comment: Brilliant idea. Sometimes we are thinking too  much about easy things.